# Which sentence is more appropriate?

Tags: sentence-construction

I have a simple question. Assume there are two variables *min* and *max*, *min*=0 and *max*=1. Now, there is a variable called *A*. *A* can take the values `0,0.2,0.4...0.8,and 1`. I want to describe *A* in my writing. Is appropriate the following sentence to describe *A* ?

> A take a discrete value  within the range of  0 to 1 by step 0.2.

I think my sentence is not right.

Comment: If you indeed are submitting this to a journal, consider reposting this question to math.SE with the `terminology` tag, and preferably, with context. As an undergraduate majoring in math, I still see problems with how _I_ would rephrase your sentence (`A takes a discrete value within [0.0, 1.0] by a step of 0.2.`), and would defer to the expertise of others in that community.

Answer (score 1):

1) Let's first fix your sentence to be *grammatically correct*:

> A) A **takes** discrete **values** within the range of **0.0** to **1.0**<sup>1</sup> by step  0.2.  (Sing/Pl)
>
> B) A **takes a** discrete **value** within the range of **0.0** to **1.0** by step 0.2.  (Sing/Pl)
>
> <sup>1. Note the ***possible technical fix*** of specifying the precision in the range consistently.</sup>

2) If this is your actual requirement, one may consider simplifying as follows:

> **FROM YOUR QUESTION(!!): "A can take the values 0.0, 0.2, 0.4, ... 0.8, 1.0.**
>
> **OR**
>
> **Variable A can be assigned one of the following: {0.0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 1.0} (This answer would, by definition, indicate discrete values since they are listed.)**

3) **Semantics:**  You are most likely using the word "discrete" correctly: to emphasize the step 0.2 size.  I'm not sure it's *necessary* given a clear definition. (Though perhaps that is part of your requirement's style guide.) But there are other possible interpretations: in some applications, it could be considered a very small range of a very low-precision, continuous value. "Just sayin". :)

Comment: @CoolHandLouis.Thankful for your answer. I am actually using the discrete values. As you now, the continuous values can take every value between [0,1] based on the mentioned assumptions in my question. I will use your first sentence and I hope that it be fit, because I want to submit my paper to a prestigious journal.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of field will this be?  Pure maths? I'm sure you're better to determine your needs for your field for this. I come from practical CompSci, in which (for most languages) all values are effectively discrete in implementation, while some may be considered continuous by semantics. Sizes of planets to the nearest mile could be considered continuous as could size of planets to the nearest 2 miles, 5 miles, 10 miles.  (Also note I changed my answer regarding "discrete" about the same time you commented.)

Comment: @Finder, please see my comment on your original post. While Louis' answer is fine from a generic English perspective, I still see reason to disagree with the way his sentences have been phrased (e.g. exclusive vs. inclusive ranges, where does your step start, is discrete really necessary, the distinction between "takes discrete value***s***" and "takes ***a*** discrete value", etc.).

Comment: @CoolHandLouis.Thankful again. It is not Pure maths. It is about computer science. My purpose of the requested question was only to focus on Grammatical point that u help me well. However, my English is not very well and every make a sentence, takes much time of me.